# How to combine Boolean AND with Boolean OR in Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, querydsl

Query: Get employee name "Mahesh" whose id is "200" and joining datetime is in a given date range and his epf status must be either 'NOK' or 'WRN'.  (Possible values of epf_status are {OK,NOK,WRN,CANCELLED}.

I have written the following query, that matches epf_status also with OK, CANCELLED, but it must only match when epf_status is either 'NOK' or 'WRN'.  What else do I need to change to make it work, as required?

```json
GET myindex01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "empname": { "query": "Mahesh", "operator": "AND" }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "empid": { "query": "200", "operator": "AND" }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "joining_datetime": {
              "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2022-06-24T23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        { "match": { "epf_status": "NOK" } },
        { "match": { "epf_status": "WRN" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### SAMPLE DATA:

```json
{"Mahesh","200","2022-04-01","OK"}
{"Mahesh","200","2022-04-01","NOK"}
{"Mahesh","200","2022-04-01","WRN"}
{"Mahesh","200","2022-04-01","CANCELLED"}
```

### REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```json
{"Mahesh","200","2022-04-01","NOK"}
{"Mahesh","200","2022-04-01","WRN"}
```

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected document to reproduce your issue and make it work according to your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

You could be using the [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query for that I believe.

> Returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field.

## To solve

```json
GET myindex01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "empname": { "query": "Mahesh", "operator": "AND" }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "empid": { "query": "200", "operator": "AND" }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "joining_datetime": {
              "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2022-06-24T23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        { "terms": { "epf_status": ["NOK", "WRN"] } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The "keyword" mapping towards epf_status is also required with "terms" query.